# How does my app know what private key to use

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish

I have an app that runs on GlassFish 3.x. It communicates to a remote server over https. In my cacerts file I've added the server certs. In my keystore.jks I added the private key the company running the remote server issued me. This works great on Glassfish 2.x, however on 3.x they remote server keeps complaining that the key I have is invalid.

If I remove the key from the keystore I get the same error. It's as if it's not even loading the key, which has got me wondering how does the app / container know which key I need

My connection code looks like this:

```
public class SSLSocket {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SSLSocket.class);
private ConnectionProperties connectionProperties;

public TuSSLSocket(ConnectionProperties connectionProperties) {
    this.connectionProperties = connectionProperties;
}

public SSLSocket getSSLSocket() throws Exception{
    SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(connectionProperties.getHost(), connectionProperties.getPort());
    socket.setSoTimeout(90000);

    return socket;
}

}
```

I set the Host and Port accordingly, but no where do I say go look for this alias in the keystore. So... how does the app know what alias to grab?

Comment: Just to clarify "In my keystore.jks I added the private key the company running the remote server issued me" doesn't happen. No one will give you their private key. What you have is their public key.

Comment: Could be... keytool -list etc... said it was a private key.

Comment: If it really is a private key sourced from elsewhere you should immediately call security. That private key is worthless as it is known to more than one party. It doesn't serve to uniquely identify you as intended, and resulting transactions are non-repudiable on your part, so it doesn't provide the remote server company any level of security at all. You should generate your own private key and certificate, and get the certificate signed by a CA.

Answer (score 0):

Explaining two way ssl and all that jazz is exhausting. I will try to find a useful link. However, for your information when an applicaiton deployed in glassfish acts as a client to communicating with a server over SSL ( for instance LDAP server realm configured through an SSL port), it will use glassfish server's identity certificate (from its keystore) as its client certificate.

But if you are explicitly coding for SSL handshake, client application is responsible for selecting the keystore, and presenting the certificate as part of the handshake.

Since it is working in a previous version of Glassfish, the same code should work for you. It is very likely that your problem is related to configuration. I am a bit confused about what you had added to server's `keystore.jks` generally the other server's certificate is added to the trust store `cacerts.jks`

A [useful glassfish ssl example](http://www.nolte-schamm.za.net/2011/06/glassfish-ssl/)

An [SSL Socket client example](http://www.herongyang.com/JDK/SSL-Socket-Client-Example-SslSocketClient.html)

[Example of choosing keystore in client.](http://www.rap.ucar.edu/staff/paddy/cacerts/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the examples. None of these show how the app is finding the alias.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to accomplish this
The first:

Open the following path from the admin console page.

- configuration
- your cluster/instance configuration.
- jvm settings
- jvm options
- you will find this line some where in the list of items
  -Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as

Change the s1as value to the certificate alias you want to use.

The other option is to add a system property to your code
System.setProperty("com.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias", "your certificate alias");